# What's the difference between ref- prefix and # in Template reference variable (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I want to understand the difference between template reference variable notations as mentioned below in the input text boxes.

```
<input type="text" name='name' #name [(ngModel)]='model'>
<input type="text" name='name' ref-name [(ngModel)]='model'>
```

What's the difference between using **#name** and **ref-name**.
Does the scope of the variable changes on using ref-name ?
Can anybody please suggest the best practice and reason ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are two different syntaxes for literally exactly the same thing.

You can think of it this way: some people (and editors) don't like the new '#variable' syntax, so Angular provides an option to use the exact same functionality using a more 'palatable' syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Template reference variable is a variable using which we can access DOM properties. A reference variable refers to its attached the element, component or directive. It can be accessed anywhere in the entire template.

```
<input type="text" name='name' #name [(ngModel)]='model'>
```

#name declares a name variable on an  element.
The reference #... now always means ref-.
Use # or a ref- outside of *ngFor.
And you can refer following URL:http://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-template-reference-variable-example

Answer (score 0):

`Template reference variable is a variable using which we can access DOM properties.`

Using template reference variable we access the values of DOM element properties. Template reference variable is declared using # and ref- as a prefix, for example, `#item` and `ref-item`.

## Example : template reference variable using input textbox

```
<input type="text" #name placeholder="Enter your name" />
```

Here `#name` is template reference variable, to fetch DOM properties we do follow

`name.placeholder` it give "placeholder of our textbox" if we have specified.

`name.value` it give us to "value" of our textbox.

`name.type` it give us to "type" of our textbox.

Here is my example which I created.

HTML Page

[image: my html page]

Output

[image: output]

you can do same thing with **`ref-name`** reference variable.