# In *ngFor which should I use: # keyword or let Variable

Tags: angular

I am learning angular but I am alittle bit confused when I use *ngFor. There are two types of syntax I see.

1 `*ngFor='let item of items'` and

2 `*ngFor='#item of items'`, 
so my questions are
1) what is the difference between # keyword or javascript variable let?
2) which one is better and why?

Comment: `*ngFor='#item of items` was used in older angular versions and should not be used in new projects. They basically do the same thing.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592556/whats-the-difference-between-ref-prefix-and-in-template-reference-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before - '#' outside *ngFor meant a reference in the template/view, while inside *ngFor it meant a local variable.

In latest version of angular it's changed because it was confusing.

Now '#' is used for a reference instead of an input variable inside the template, while in structural directives(*ngIf, *ngFor etc.) the use of '#' is deprecated.

It is better to use 'let' inside *ngFor and '#' outside the *ngFor.

Learn more here:
[*ngFor: meaning of # vs let?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976494/ngfor-meaning-of-vs-let)